# Open video file from Assets folder and play it

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayerviewcontroller

I am trying to load a .mp4 file that I added inside assets/videos folder but I fail. This is my code so far:

```
- (IBAction)showVideo:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *strPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,@"myVideoName.mp4"];
    NSLog(@"strPath %@",strPath);

    NSURL *videosURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath];

    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videosURL];

    // create a player view controller
    AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    controller.player = player;
    [player play];
}
```

I think I am doing something wrong with the video file path. 
Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I replaced this:

```
 NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *strPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,videoName];
    NSLog(@"strPath %@",strPath);
```

with this:

```
 NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
 NSString *myFile = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"videoName" ofType: @"mp4"];
```